# Java: How to use a sentinel value to quit a program when the user wants

Tags: java

The only thing i am missing is to use a sentinel value, like zero, to quit the loop when the user wants, even without enter any gussing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomGuessing {

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //This application prompt to the user to guess a number. The user can still playing until
    //guess the number or want to quit
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randNum = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
        System.out.println(randNum);

        System.out.println("\t\tHi-Lo Game with Numbers\t\t\n\t   Guess a number between 1 and 100!!!\n");

        String ans;
        int attemptsCount = 0;

        do {

            System.out.print("Guess the number: ");
            int input = scan.nextInt();

            while(input != randNum){

                attemptsCount++;

                if(input < randNum){
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("low guessing\nEnter new number: ");
                    input = scan.nextInt();
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("high guessing\nEnter new number: ");
                    input = scan.nextInt();
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Congrats!!! You guess right\nAttempts: "+attemptsCount);

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("You want to play again (yes/no): ");
            ans = scan.next();

            randNum = rand.nextInt(100) + 1; //generate new random number between same above range, 
                                             //if the user wants to keep playing.

        }while (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));


    }
}
```

Comment: You want to quit when user types in 0? `while (scan.nextInt() != 0)`

Comment: This is quite similar to the exit condition for the while loop that you already implemented. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

```
// inside do loop
System.out.print("Guess the number (-1 to quit): ");
int input = scan.nextInt();
if (input == -1) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code for exiting totaly:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Nit pick: This is just my personal opinion on the subject, so I'm not going to downvote you or anything like that, but a program should have a single entry point and a single exit point (methods and functions should follow the same concept), which prevents you from running into unexpected terminations. A better (long term) solution would be to test the `while-loop`s exit conditions appropriately. But like I say, that's just me ;)

Comment: I'm a bit new on java and i am using a book which hava this problem to solve. First prompt to the user if want to exit the program by using a sentinel value, and next if the user guess correctly or quit ask if he/she want to play again. It is like the user already quit the program but you have to be shure the user wants.